# Mobile responsiveness not working on Samsung Note 21 and iPhone 14 but working on all other devices. Can't replicate error from Chrome dev tools

Tags: html, css

I am currently having a unique error. A landing page is very responsive on all other mobiles I have tried: https://bluehedge.netlify.app. However, it seems to appear this way on the web owner's device:[Samsung device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZHCq.jpg) [iPhone device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXmBU.jpg)

Here is the HTML for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Bluehedge Realtors</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
  
>! <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css"
>! integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw=="
>! crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  
>! <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/js/regular.js"
>! integrity="sha512-fBpv5+XQl3VrI7djEW+whWKTM+hUNGoqBA16mxfEvdVbzWe3P8Bsb+TLYKSN6hJUzkbxFTxLwB+IFWYw+EGtqw=="
>! crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- <h1>Hello World!</h1> -->
  <main>
    <div class="main-content">

      <img class="image" src="./bluehedge-logo.png" />

      <h1>Welcome to Bluehedge Realtors</h1>

      <section>
        <div>
          <h2>Our Socials</h2>
        </div>


        <div class="buttons-layout">
          <div>
            <button id="facebook">
              <a href="">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
                <span>Facebook</span>
              </a>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button id="instagram">
              <a href=""><i
                  class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i><span>Instagram</span>
              </a>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button id="whatsapp">
              <a href="">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i>
                <span>WhatsApp</span>
              </a>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button id="website"><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-earth-africa"></i><span>Our
                  Website</span></a></button>
          </div>

          <p class="address">BLUEHEDGE REALTORS<br />
            Suite 205/232, Block H, Ikota Shopping Complex
            VGC, Lekki, Lagos.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

The CSS:

```
@import url("");

body {
  background: url("./Atlantic.jpg");
  background-size: cover;

  overflow: hidden;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.image {
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
}

.main-content {
  text-align: center;
}

.buttons-layout {
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  animation: reveal 1.5s 0.3s;
  /* margin-top: 40px; */
}

button {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 18px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* background-color: transparent; */
  width: 550px;
  height: 55px;
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* border-width: 1px; */
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 1px 11px 12px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.63);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 11px 12px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.63);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 11px 12px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.63);
  /* border-color: blue; */
}

button:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

button span:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0.48, 0.13, 1.03);
  color: #fff;
}

button a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  /* width: 300px; */
  gap: 8px;
}

button:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}

button:hover .fa-brands {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

button:hover .fa-solid {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

#facebook:hover {
  background-color: #3b5998;
}

#whatsapp:hover {
  background-color: #25d366;
}

#instagram:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    #405de6,
    #5851db,
    #833ab4,
    #c13584,
    #e1306c,
    #fd1d1d,
    #f56040,
    #f77737,
    #fcaf45,
    #ffdc80
  );
}

#website:hover {
  background-color: #add8e6;
}

.address {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.address span {
  font-weight: bold;
}

@keyframes reveal {
  from {
    margin-top: 70px;
  }

  to {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
}

@media (width <= 880px) {
  body {
    background: url("./mobile-bg.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  section {
    padding-top: 30px;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .address {
    font-size: 10px;
  }

  button {
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 15px;
  }
}
```

I have tried all responsive tools I can find. From Chrome/Edge developer tools to all other developer tools I can find to try to replicate that non-responsive screen. However, they all seem to appear fine on those tools except the owner's phones.

Comment: thats a reason why you should test on actual devices not on Chrome Dev Tools. Personally I would recommend the usage of FF for testing over Chrome and not to use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />` as I see no approach to counter the loss of DPR feature that this meta tag cause. PS a responsive layout will work with relative units such as `em` and `rem`. It will not use hardcoded `px` units. Espacially with the loss of the DPR, `22px` as h1 font size is about 1/3 of the default size.

Comment: Sorry, what is FF?

Comment: Are you just running out of space on the real devices? And I see no width or height settings for the flexes to have to conform to. FF=Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. It was the @media query syntax:

```
@media(width <= 700px) {
// Mobile responsiveness..
}
```

Apparently, not all mobile browsers seem to recognize that syntax making the phones render the desktop view instead.

Switched to the good old media query syntax:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {}
```

...and it worked!!